# Como identificar route no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou usando um template para o menu e rodapé serem duplicados em todas as páginas. Coloquei um `if` no rodapé pra quando for uma determinada rota ele mudar o conteúdo, mas não é isso que está acontecendo, ele está interpretando toda e qualquer rota como "home". Se eu acessar a rota "empresa" ele irá até a página certa, mas o rodapé permanecerá o mesmo. Dando um `echo Route::currentRouteName();` só obtive "home".

### Routes

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index'));
Route::get('home', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index'));
Route::get('empresa', array('as' => 'empresa', 'uses' => 'EmpresaController@index'));
```

### Template

```
@if(str_is('home', Route::currentRouteName()))
    <div class="pure-g">
        <div class="pure-u-1">
            <footer id="rodapeHome">
                <p id="responsabilidadeSocialHomeRodapeTexto">Responsabilidade social também é nosso foco:</p>
                <div id="empresasResponsabilidadeSocial">
                    @foreach($acaoSocial as $acaoSocial)
                        <img src="assets/images/acaosocial/{{$acaoSocial->imagem}}" />
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </footer>       
        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-1" id="caixaDireitosAutorais">
            <p id="tituloRodapeDireitosReservados">‎© 2014 Titina Leão - Todos os direitos reservados.<p/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Antes

```
Route::get('empresa', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'EmpresaController@index'));
```

## Depois

```
Route::get('empresa', array('as' => 'empresa', 'uses' => 'EmpresaController@index'));
```

Eu não troquei o `as`, que é o nome da route. Ctrl+C e Ctrl+V mais desatenção = bebês focas mortos.